# How to send custom form total value to CCAvenue Payment Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, payment-gateway

I have form which is get details form customer and also calculate amount of the product, how can i pass total value which is get form and pass to CCAvenue payment page.

My form :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Upgrade Cost</title>
        <script src="css/googleapis/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="css/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Ajax data -->
        <div class="container"> 

            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>KoluPadi Upgrade Form</h1>      
                </div>
            </div>

                <form action='ccavRequestHandler.php' method='POST' > 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first_name">First Name :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="first_name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="last_name">Last Name :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="last_name">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Address :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Address" name="address">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="city">City :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" name="city">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="state_province">State/Province :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter State/Province" name="state_province">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="zip_postal_code">Zip/Postal Code :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zip/Postal Code" id="zip_postal_code" name="zip_postal_code">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="country">Country :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Country" id="country" name="country">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email_id">Email Id :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Id" name="email_id">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="mobile_number">Mobile Number :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" name="mobile_number">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="i_have">I have :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <select id="old" class="form-control" placeholder="Select I have" name="i_have">

                            <option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
                            <option value = "three_compact">3 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "three_regular">3 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "three_triple">3 Triple</option>
                            <option value = "five_compact">5 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "five_regular">5 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "five_triple">5 Triple</option>
                            <option value = "seven_compact">7 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "seven_regular">7 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "seven_triple">7 Triple</option>
                            <option value = "nine_compact">9 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "nine_regular">9 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "nine_triple">9 Triple</option>   
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>




                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="i_want">I want :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <select id="new" class="form-control" placeholder="Select I want" name="i_want">

                            <option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
                            <option value = "three_compact">3 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "three_regular">3 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "three_triple">3 Triple</option>
                            <option value = "five_compact">5 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "five_regular">5 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "five_triple">5 Triple</option>
                            <option value = "seven_compact">7 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "seven_regular">7 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "seven_triple">7 Triple</option>
                            <option value = "nine_compact">9 Compact</option>
                            <option value = "nine_regular">9 Regular</option>
                            <option value = "nine_triple">9 Triple</option>   
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="price">Price (Rs) :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="price" name="price"  readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="shipping_weight">Shipping Weight :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="shipping_weight" name="shipping_weight" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="shipping_cost">Shipping Cost (Rs) :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <select id="findata" class="form-control" id="shipping_cost" name="shipping_cost"  ></select>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="grand_total">Grand Total: :</label> 
                    <div class="col-sm-10">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="grand_total" name="grand_total" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>         

                <div class="form-group">        
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="pass">Pay</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>    
        </body>
    <!-- <button id="btn_check_value">Check for value</button>  -->

    <!-- Ajax Script -->

    <script>

        // Price
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#new').on('change',function(){
                var old_val = $("#old option:selected").val();
                var new_val = $("#new option:selected").val();

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_price.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { old: old_val, new: new_val},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
                        // console.log(data);
                        $('#result').html(data);
                        $('#price').val(data);

                    }
                });

            });
        });    

        // Weight
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#new').on('change',function(){
                var old_val = $("#old option:selected").val();
                var new_val = $("#new option:selected").val();

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_ship_weight.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { old: old_val, new: new_val},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
                        //console.log(data);
                        $('#show').html(data);
                        $('#shipping_weight').val(data);

                    }
                });
            });
        });

        //Shipping_cost
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#new').on('change',function(){

                var zip = $("#zip_postal_code").val();
                var country = $("#country").val();

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                // url: "ajax_ship_cost_data.php",
                url: "sp_cost.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { zip_postal_code: zip, country: country},
                success: function(data)
                     {
                        // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
                        //console.log(data);
                        $('#findata').html(data);
                        $('#shipping_cost').val(data);

                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // Grand Total
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#findata').on('change',function(){

                var price = $("#price").val();
                var shipping_cost = $("#findata").val();

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "gt.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { price: price, shipping_cost: shipping_cost },
                success: function(data)
                    {
                        // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
                        // console.log(data);
                        $('#total').html(data);
                        $('#grand_total').val(data);

                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // ###### passing data to db  #######
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#pass').on('click',function(){

                var first_name      = $("#first_name").val();
                var last_name       = $("#last_name").val();
                var address         = $("#address").val();
                var city            = $("#city").val();
                var state_province  = $("#state_province").val();
                var zip_postal_code = $("#zip_postal_code").val();
                var country         = $("#country").val();
                var email_id        = $("#email_id").val();
                var mobile_number   = $("#mobile_number").val();
                var i_have          = $("#i_have").val();
                var i_want          = $("#i_want").val();
                var price           = $("#price").val();
                var shipping_weight = $("#shipping_weight").val();
                var shipping_cost   = $("#shipping_cost").val();
                var grand_total     = $("#grand_total").val();


                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_data.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: 
                    {
                        first_name      :  first_name,
                        last_name       :  last_name,
                        address         :  address,
                        city            :  city,
                        state_province  :  state_province,
                        zip_postal_code :  zip_postal_code,
                        country         :  country,
                        email_id        :  email_id,
                        mobile_number   :  mobile_number,
                        i_have          :  i_have,
                        i_want          :  i_want,
                        price           :  price,
                        shipping_weight :  shipping_weight,
                        shipping_cost   :  shipping_cost,
                        grand_total     :  grand_total
                    }
                    // ,
                    // success: function(data)
                    // {
                        // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
                        // console.log(data);
                        // $('#pass').html(data);
                        // $('#price').val(data);

                    // }
                });

            });
        });

    </script> 
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.